# Auto-Populate Related To Field on Email in Salesforce Email Composer

Tags: apex, trigger, email

I am trying to auto-populate the Related To field in the Salesforce Email Composer that pops up when I click on an email address on an Account record. Please see screenshot below:

[image]

Any idea how I can achieve this? The email field 'Primary Contact Email' is actually rolling up an email field from another record- which is why I don't think the Related To field is automatically populating.

Thank you.